PfSense HA Sync does not work (Error: Operation timed out)
i set up a HA Envoirement right now. All is working well except teh sync of settings.
Sync Interfaces is up and State Sync is set on both firewalls to this. CARP VIP are working, state sync is sucessful to. I can ping one firewall to the other and reverse over the Sync-Net.
Firewall rules in Sync tab: Allow any
Both FW are on HTTPS Port 444
Both FW are on Version 2.7.2-RELEASE
Both FW have exactly the same interfaces
Master PF: 172.22.1.2
Secondary PF: 172.22.1.3
Syslog Master PF:
Nov 16 15:54:22     kernel      carp: demoted by 0 to 0 (pfsync bulk fail)
Nov 16 15:54:01     php-fpm     44568   /rc.filter_synchronize: The pfSense software configuration version of the other member could not be determined. Skipping synchronization to avoid causing a problem!
Nov 16 15:54:01     php-fpm     44568   /rc.filter_synchronize: XMLRPC versioncheck: -- 23.3
Nov 16 15:54:01     php-fpm     44568   /rc.filter_synchronize: New alert found: A communications error occurred while attempting to call XMLRPC method host_firmware_version: Unable to connect to tls://172.22.1.3:444. Error: Operation timed out
Nov 16 15:54:01     php-fpm     44568   /rc.filter_synchronize: A communications error occurred while attempting to call XMLRPC method host_firmware_version: Unable to connect to tls://172.22.1.3:444. Error: Operation timed out
Nov 16 15:53:51     php-fpm     44568   /rc.filter_synchronize: Beginning XMLRPC sync data to https://172.22.1.3:444/xmlrpc.php. 

Syslog on Secondary:
Nov 16 15:49:33     kernel      carp: demoted by 0 to 0 (pfsync bulk fail)
Nov 16 15:48:29     php-fpm     46926   /system_hasync.php: Configuring CARP settings finalize...
Nov 16 15:48:29     php-fpm     46926   /system_hasync.php: pfsync done in 1 seconds.
Nov 16 15:48:28     kernel      carp: demoted by 0 to 0 (pfsync bulk start)
Nov 16 15:48:28     php-fpm     46926   /system_hasync.php: waiting for pfsync...
Nov 16 15:48:28     check_reload_status     428     Syncing firewall 

I read that i have to disable DNS Resolver: same issue. If i uncehck all sync boxes and try just to sync e.g. "Firewall Rules": same issue.
Any ideas?

Solution:
I connected the two PFS with a virtual Switch (VXLAN+IPSEC). For this i had to lower the MTU to 1360.
Unfortunatelly the Adapter in PFSense was set to 1500 and not appling for the new MTU.
Setting down the MTU (in my case to 1360) manually in the SYNC-Interface-Options solved the problem.

Please have a look at Can I answer my own question? and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation (See also: Accept Your Own Answers.
